# how to add push notifications in my existing android app using pushbots

Tags: java, android, eclipse, push-notification

I am trying to implement push notifications in my existing android app using PushBots (http://www.pushbots.com) I have followed all the steps mentioned checked and rechecked the steps.  But when I run the app  it suddenly crashes but never shows any error.
I am sure about the keys in the MainActvitiy.java they are correct.

I have simply added the .jar into the libs folder
![enter image description here][1]

```
MainActivity.java
 ----------------
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private  String SENDER_ID = "1017942666064";
private  String PUSHBOTS_APPLICATION_ID = "53a8a9d71d0ab1c1428b4569";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Pushbots.init(this, SENDER_ID,PUSHBOTS_APPLICATION_ID);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

### Manifest.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.pushboss"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>

<permission android:name="com.example.pushboss.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.pushboss.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.pushboss.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.example.pushboss.MESSAGE" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.pushbots.push.PBMsg"/>
<activity android:name="com.pushbots.push.PBListener"/>
<receiver
android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
<intent-filter>
    <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <category android:name="com.example.pushboss" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.pushbots.push.MsgReceiver" />
<service android:name="com.pushbots.push.GCMIntentService" />
<service android:name="org.openudid.OpenUDID_service" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="org.openudid.GETUDID" />
 </intent-filter>
</service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really look to google, this is a pretty straight forward functionality. The main way to do this on iOS is to use parse, you can do the same with android, here's a tutorial:

[how to add push notifications in my existing android app using pushbots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376075/how-to-add-push-notifications-in-my-existing-android-app-using-pushbots)

Here is another example using Google cloud API

https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/android-push-notifications

Comment: That tutorial link :(